# How to remove duplicate values in assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, string, associative-array

I have an associate array. I want to remove duplicate values if the value has appear first. Let's say if `DC-30` has appear first, remove all DC-30 in the associate array. If `HSD-M` has appeared already, remove all `HSD-M` in the associate array. I'm doing all of this in `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` if that makes any difference. Any help here?

```
string(5) "DC-30" 
string(5) "DC-30" 
string(10) "GigaDigHD2" 
string(11) "Turbo-Frame" 
string(5) "HSD-M" 
string(5) "HSD-M" 
string(5) "HSD-M" 
string(5) "HSD-M"
```

EDIT: These array values are not hard coded. They are from a table in the database, that's why I want to remove duplicated values.

Wanted output is:

```
string(5)  "DC-30" 
string(10) "GigaDigHD2" 
string(11) "Turbo-Frame" 
string(5)  "HSD-M"
```

2nd EDIT:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $tester_name = $row['tester_name'];
    $board_name = $row['board_name'];
    $config = $row['config'];
    $req_config = $row['configuration'];

    echo $bomb = array_unique($board_name, SORT_REGULAR); //Edited here

    $ex_req_config = explode(",", $req_config);
    $count_req_config =  count($ex_req_config);

    $match = 0;

    foreach($ex_req_config as $value)
    {
        $number = strlen($value);
        $arr = str_split($value, $number);

        if(in_array($config, $arr))
        {
            $match += 1;
            $match /= ($count_req_config / 100);
        }
    }

    /*  echo "<tr class = \"thisRow\">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class = \"match\">$match%</td>
             </tr>";*/
}
```

Comment: Add a check. Store into array once only.

Comment: `array_unique($your_array,SORT_REGULAR)`

Comment: @b0s3 Not sure how to do the store array once only. These values are queried from a table and stored into a associate array with multiple values.

Comment: @splash58 Alright, just edited in.

Comment: then Uchiha 6 is right. Use his suggestion

Comment: Most often, this is something that can be done when querying the database; i.e. only ask the database for the unique values. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @splash58 I edited the codes I'm using in, getting a `Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array` cause `$board_name` is a string, what should I use?

Comment: @salathe Nope, it's not an option for me. I would've done that if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a grouping inside the query itself is not an option, initialise an array before the loop starts and manage it inside the loop:

```
$boards = [];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // ...
    $boards[$board_name] = $board_name;
}
```

At the end of the loop `$boards` will be an array with all the unique values.